# How to send multiple parameters in AngularJS $http.post to Web API controller action method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

How to send multiple parameters in an angularjs $http.post to web api controller action method.

Below is my code.

**AngularJS code**

```
var complexObj = { prop1: "value", prop2: "value" };

var id = 100;

var data = { id: id, complexObj: complexObj };

$http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'http://localhost/api/WebApiController/MethodName',
       data: data
       }).success(function (data, status) {
                //do something...
            });


$http.post('http://localhost/api/WebApiController/MethodName', data)
     .success(function (data, status) {
                     //do something...
                 });
```

**Web API controller**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/WebApiController")]
public class WebApiController: ApiController
{
    [Route("MethodName")]
    public ReturnValue WebApiAction(string id,ComplexObj complexObj)
    {
        // process request and return data...
    }
}
```

I am getting below response message in fiddler.

> {   "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request
>   URI 'http://localhost/api/WebApiController/MethodName'.",
>   "messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller
>   'WebApiController' that matches the request." }

When I send the complexObj alone, its hitting the web api,but all properties are null or set to default values.

What am I doing wrong? How can I send two or more parameters(both complex objects and string/int) in $http.post? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried serializing the object (JSON.stringify(...))

Comment: @ItaloAyres yes, its not working.

Comment: What's the definition of ComplexObj?  Also, what happens when you set var id = '100';

Comment: I know that in Spring, we can use @RequestBody to post a JSON object. If you are using another framework, you can try to use something similar.

Comment: @Josh 'id' is just an another parameter, i need to pass to web api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web API doesn't support multiple post parameters in this way.

Your best bet is to roll up Id into ComplexObj and post it as a single parameter.

```
complexObj.id = id;
var data = complexObj;
```

Update your signature to take just a single object.

```
[Route("MethodName")]
public ReturnValue WebApiAction(ComplexObj complexObj)
{
    // process request and return data...
}
```

If you absolutely want to be able to post data like this, consider Rick Strahl's [post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API) on creating a custom parameter binder.

Comment: Rick Strahl's solution only supports simple types. To support complex objects, check out [MultiPostParameterBinding](https://github.com/keith5000/MultiPostParameterBinding)